# drupal 6 VIEWS - I'm stumped

Tags: drupal

I've created a view (Drupal 6) that gets put on the users profile page.

The view is supposed to list all the images that the user has uploaded.  However, the view is showing every uploaded image by all users.

(When a user uploads an image, it first gets approved by me, and then posted by me and displayed on the homepage with a credit to them and a link to their user profile -- so they are not the "author" of the post, I always am.)

How can I limit the photos displaying on their  user profile to just show the images uploaded by that particular user?

Thank you.

Comment: Your workflow seems flawed to me. The author should be the author and you should just change the state from unpublished to published (or whatever) instead of becoming the author.

Comment: How are you tracking the user who uploads the image? A user reference field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arguments handling: add argument - User ID, check "if argument not provided" and select php code: `return arg(1); // if views shown as block and you want to show it in user profile, path will like user/UID, so arg(1) return UID.`

2Ted: hello Ted! php code will absolutely secured, if you will check it, for example via [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)() function. Also users cann't get any images, becuase Views wil use Block display, and you cann't provide for this arguments directly.

2user967969: Additionally about approving: You can create second field, where you will store user profile UID. So for my above text you should use this field for argument handling, instead of user uid.

Comment: You are correct that an argument is the answer, but the php code is a potential security issue, depending on the security requirements, as any user can now can get any image. Also, the original poster said that the uid for the node does not correspond to the user who uploaded the image so the argument is flawed even though an argument will be the answer.

Comment: Hello Ted.  Are you able to help me form this argument?  I'm really not sure how to filter out the other users' images.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  It now functions perfectly.  :)

Comment: user967969: Nikit means that you should accept his answer since it works. There is a checkbox that only you (the person who asked the question) can use to mark the answer as correct. That will give Nikit points, which he earned by correctly answering your question. Welcome to slashdot.

Comment: Thanks Ted for advicing, I am forgot that some users didn't know about this :)